# I'm unable to see system.debug statements on a trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I created a trigger that looks like this:

```
trigger DG_CM_Trigger on CampaignMember (before insert) {
System.debug('DG_CM_Trigger - START');
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        DG_CampaignMember_Class.populateCustomAttributes(trigger.New);
    }
    System.debug('DG_CM_Trigger - END');
}
```

As you can see, I have system debug statements at the beginning and end of the trigger.  When I look at the debug logs, I can see that the trigger is called...

```
09:42:46.524 (524616000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01qc00000004eIV|DG_CM_Trigger on CampaignMember trigger event BeforeInsert for [new]
09:42:46.540 (540035000)|METHOD_ENTRY| [1]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.DG_CampaignMember_Class()
09:42:46.540 (540101000)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|DG_CampaignMember_Class
09:42:46.540 (540725000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[4]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.populateCustomAttributes(LIST<CampaignMember>)
09:42:46.543 (543070000)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[114]|01pc00000006aDT|<init>()
09:42:46.543 (543199000)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[114]|01pc00000006aDT|<init>()
09:42:46.543 (543273000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[114]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.LeadFieldMapping()
09:42:46.548 (548241000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[41]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.getCMFieldMapping()
09:42:46.693 (693286000)|METHOD_EXIT|[41]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.getCMFieldMapping()
09:42:46.703 (703469000)|METHOD_EXIT|[114]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.LeadFieldMapping()
09:42:46.781 (781457000)|METHOD_EXIT|[4]|01pc00000006aDT|DG_CampaignMember_Class.populateCustomAttributes(LIST<CampaignMember>)
09:42:46.781 (781790000)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|DG_CM_Trigger on CampaignMember trigger event BeforeInsert for [new]
```

However, I do not see my System.debug statement.  I had debug statements in the class as well, but does do not show either.  I have set the debug log filters to *apex code: debug* and *system: debug* (the rest are info).  I even tried setting the 'override log filters' on the CampaignMember_Class and also set the levels to *apex code: debug* and *system:debug*.  I can't seem to figure out why the debug statements are not showing up on the log which is making debugging extremely difficult.  Peharps there is some kind of user setting I'm not aware of?  User permissions? (although I'm in the admin profile, but I perhaps something in the profile settings that is not set?)  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the LoggingLevel as the first parameter to the System.debug calls. E.g.

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'hello');
```

Also, if this is a deployed managed package Salesforce will hide all logging.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it out, but no success. And to give more information, I see other debug statments in the log from other triggers / classes (not created by me). So, I can rule out profile settings and log filter issues since if that were the case, no debug statements would appear. It's something with my filter / class. I deleted and re-added the filter, and tried changing the class versions (the other trigger / class are lower versions since they were create early last year).  No dice.  Very frustrating.

Comment: Maybe try something more drastic in the trigger like adding an `System.assert(false, 'BOOM!');` or throwing an exception. It does sound like the overide log filters is in play. I think with a sufficiently low log level you can see the override being applied.